# Is "normal scheme" defined in EGA?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In answering a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76349/is-there-a-connected-non-affine-scheme-s-such-that-it-is-the-union-of-rings-of/76365#76365) on this site yesterday, I was led to introduce a non-separated scheme, which I said  was  normal.
However when I tried to check the definition of "normal scheme" in EGA , in order to make sure that "normal" didn't have "separated" in its definition, I was surprised to find that I couldn't find the definition, although "normal prescheme" *is* used in many places (which seems to indicate that normal doesn't imply separated, else the authors would have said normal scheme: schemes were supposed to be separated in contradistinction to preschemes).

Another ambiguity:   it is not clear to me whether for Grothendieck-Dieudonné, "normal" only depends on the local rings of the scheme : do they consider that the spectrum of the product of two copies of a field $k$ is normal, even though $k\times k$ is not a domain, hence not an integrally closed domain ?
[My guess is "yes", but I don't want to guess]

So, my question is:**Do the EGA contain a definition of "normal (pre)scheme" ?**
I'm interested because I have never used a definition at odds with EGA, and I have no intention to start now...

Answer (score 12):

Normal ringed spaces are defined in EGA $0_I$, (4.1.4), normal rings in $0_I$ (6.5.1) (with a strangely phrased comment which first led me to believe that the definition would be repeated for schemes in Chapter I, but it couldn't find this). In any case, a scheme is normal iff its local rings are integrally closed domains.

Comment: Agree, see, e.g. Serre's normality criterion EGA IV$_2$ (5.8.6).

Comment: @Leo Alonso: this is a very convincing reference. May I suggest that you transform your comment into an answer, so that I (and no doubt others) can upvote you?

Comment: @Laurent. Thank you very much: I wasn't aware of these very interesting and convincing references. (Readers: beware that Laurent's reference $0_I$ (6.5.1) is to the second edition of EGA I, the one edited by Springer .The first reference is common to both editions.)

Comment: Both you, Laurent, and Leo have given perfect answers to my question. Since, unfortunately, I can accept only one answer, I decided to encourage the more junior user.

Answer (score 11):

Normality for schemes (as opposed to general ringed spaces) seems not to be treated in EGA until $\S$5 in Chapter IV. It is discussed in the context of properties R$_n$ and S$_n$. Serre's normality criterion (Normal is equivalent to R$_1$ *and* S$_2$) is proved in EGA IV$_2$ (5.8.6). The definition is briefly recalled at the beginning of the proof.

Comment: It is astonishing how little is a role the notion of normality plays in Grothendieck's algebraic geometry, when we remember how central
a notion it was for Zariski and his school, just one decade earlier.

